# Cassandra keyring issue

Tags: cassandra, apt, keyring

I am installing cassandra following the steps in the official website coming to the step of `sudo apt-get` update I got this

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
W: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
```

I tried several times with several methods to export a key or multiple ones but I got the nothing exported response can anyone help me solve this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're using Ubuntu with a version > 22. It looks like  `apt-key` has been deprecated, which means that `apt-get` can't use the existing keys in the old format to get out to its repositories. It has been replaced with the `gpg` command, which requires the gpg keys to be in a different location and format.

A more thorough description of this problem can be found in this article - [Ubuntu: apt-key is deprecated](https://medium.com/@glegoux/ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-apt-key-is-deprecated-2dbbee8aec84)

**tl;dr;**

To fix this, we need to move the current GPG public keys from the file `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` and the folder `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` to `/etc/apt/keyrings/` with the correct format.

Here is a quick synapsis of one of the steps from the article, about 2/3 of the way down:

> Identify the keys to migrate with:

```
$ apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   dsa1024 2007-03-08 [SC]
      4CCA 1EAF 950C EE4A B839  76DC A040 830F 7FAC 5991
uid           [ unknown] Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   elg2048 2007-03-08 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2021-10-26 [S] [expires: 2024-10-25]
sub   rsa4096 2023-02-15 [S] [expires: 2026-02-14]
These 2 keys can be migrated into the same file:

sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d && \
sudo apt-key export -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.asc \
D38B4796 7FAC5991
```

> The migration can be done in one command with:

```
sudo apt-key export D38B4796 7FAC5991 | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/keyrings/google.gpg
```

> However, 2 steps may be preferable. Also the key `7FAC5991` is obsolete and could be deleted.

> Now explore the format of the created file:

```
$ file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.asc
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.asc: PGP public 
key block Public-Key (old)
```

> The format is the old textual format PGP ASCII-Armor, we need to export it in a binary format OpenPGP supported by gpg and move it to the right folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings/ \
&& cat /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.asc \
| sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg
```

> Now the format is correct:

```
$ file /etc/apt/keyrings/google.gpg
/etc/apt/keyrings/google.gpg: OpenPGP Public Key Version 4, 
Created Thu Mar  8 20:17:10 2007, DSA (1024 bits); User ID; Signature; 
OpenPGP Certificate
```

> You can remove the public keys with:

```
sudo apt-key del D38B4796 7FAC5991
```

Give the article a read. This way the instructions will make more sense as you go through them.